# Laravel's NotFoundHttpException won't dissapear in Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm using Nginx with Laravel and I keep getting a `NotFoundHttpException` error.
Nginx won't log anything. I've also tried to add `die('Test');` inside my `public/index.php` file, but that won't be dumped as well.

My Nginx `server` block looks like this:

```
server {
    listen          0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name     test.docker.dev;

    root            /usr/share/nginx/html/docs/public;
    index           index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/default_access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/default_error.log;
}
```

Comment: Anything in your Laravel log file (storage/logs)?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here.. if you're getting a `NotFoundHttpException`, then index.php is getting called. But if you put a `die` statement in index.php, it isn't getting called. That doesn't add up -- are you sure you're editing the correct `index.php` ? Or are you receiving a generic `404` error from your browser, rather than a `NotFoundHttpException` from Laravel?

Comment: could be a problem related to this: http://serverfault.com/questions/231578/nginx-php-fpm-where-are-my-get-params